# Why does installing Cassandra on Mesos via dcos package fail with "Max retries exceeded with url: /marathon/v2/info"?

Tags: cassandra, mesos

I am trying to install Cassandra on Mesos using `dcos package install cassandra`, but I got this error message:

```
The Apache Cassandra DCOS Service implementation is alpha and there may be bugs, incomplete features, incorrect documentation or other discrepancies.
The default configuration requires 3 nodes each with 0.3 CPU shares, 1184MB of memory and 272MB of disk.
Continue installing? [yes/no] yes
Installing Marathon app for package [cassandra] version [0.2.0-1]
URL [http://localhost/marathon/v2/info] is unreachable: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /marathon/v2/info (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x31aea10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Can anyone explain me why and how to fix it?

Comment: This means that your Marathon framework is not reachable on localhost:80. Are you sure it's actually running?

Answer (score 1):

The DCOS CLI is intended for use to manage instances of Mesosphere's DCOS. The DCOS is a software stack built on top of Mesos. You can't use the DCOS CLI to manage a Marathon installation which is not running on DCOS.

Your options to fix this are either to use DCOS, which will allow you to install Cassandra using the DCOS CLI, or to try running Cassandra on Marathon yourself.

If you choose to use DCOS, you can get started using the free Community Edition from [the Mesosphere website](https://mesosphere.com/product/).

If you'd rather try running Cassandra on Marathon, there are some helpful and detailed instructions on [Marcin Brański's blog](http://3h4x.github.io/cassandra/marathon/docker/mesos/2015/03/28/cassandra-on-marathon.html) (not reproduced here as they are rather lengthy).